# Display google maps with Geotools?

Tags: google-maps, geotools

I would like to display Google maps (Raster and Vector) in Java using GeoTools. I am stuck because I am new to this library. Are there any tutorials out there that can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

geotools is not a rendering library. It a Java toolkit which can read spatial data and provides access to geometry,attributes in the data. It provides certain algorithm for geometry processing. [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html), Java Tolplogy Suite contained in GeoTools.

This was ported to C/C++ as [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/). You can try [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) which uses geotools for processing and uses OpenLayers for viewing maps. [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) defenitely allows you to display google maps.

And for the records you cant get raster/vector data from google for free using any libs available. The provide maps as a service collectively called as [WMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) (Web Map services). These dish out non georeferenced images as png/jpeg which cannot be used for any spatial operation.

Also please see the T&C for using Google Maps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to use to use OpenLayers. But I have to do a desktop this is why I am trying to use GeoTools. Is there Java library like OpenLayers ?

Comment: there are some java based libs: OpenJUMP, gvSIG, uDIG, KOSMO SAIG are some gis applications. but you can use their api to acheive the same. They support WMS but I am afraid you can use google maps, QGIS has an openlayers plugin. But its C++/Python